# FatalErrorException in ...\vendor\netresearch\jsonmapper\src\JsonMapper.php line 549: Class '\Keepa\objects\Product' not found

Tags: php, laravel

In the App directory I have added a folder Classes where my keepaAPI is getting data from amazon server.[this is my app directory and you can see the Classes folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euvt8.png)..

In the Classes folder there is a file called PriceClass.php. This PriceClass.php will create the instance of this priceclass.php on productcontroller.php [these are the files in the Classes folder and u can see the PriceClass.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrQil.png)..

Now here is ProductController.php the first 2 lines of my ProductController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Classes\PricesClass;

public function get_json_data() {

    $pricesClass = new PricesClass();
    $prices = $pricesClass->getPrices();

    die();
    return view('get_json', compact('prices'));
}
```

when I run the project, it gives me an error 
.FatalErrorException in

> G:\xamp\htdocs\solidarrow\vendor\netresearch\jsonmapper\src\JsonMapper.php
>   line 549: Class '\Keepa\objects\Product' not found

Kindly help me to fix this issue, thanks.

Comment: Could you post your `JsonMapper.php` codes? Or the class that calls the `jsonmapper` file. Also it would be nice if there is your Product.php class and other class related to that.

Comment: Jsonmapper.php contain 686 lines of code .i am using laravel5.2 framework.\htdocs\solidarrow\vendor\netresearch\jsonmapper\src\JsonMapper.php line 549:

Comment: From where did you initialized `JsonMapper()`. Could you post that class code?

Comment: Did you run `composer auto-load`?

Comment: JsonMapper is initailized in App\Classes\keepa\keepaAPI.php ..

Comment: i dont run the composer auto-load .GiamPy..will u plz tell me why we run this command

Comment: kindly help me anyone....

Comment: Could you add more informations of your codes? as we don't have any magic to see where you have the issue.